# unable to extract dumped files in .tar extention on my site

Tags: migrations, features, importing-exporting, backups

I can't extract my backup dumped with .tar extention. so i can't work with features
can I download features in .zip ?

Answer (score 1):

No. [Tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) is what's supported.

Downloading the files I generally feel is a pain though, I would encourage you to look at managing the features with Drush instead. It's often a lot faster as it mostly enables you to skip the whole download step.